# How does address resolution work with multicast, specifically IPv6?

Tags: ip, ipv6, arp, multicast, udp

If I want to send an IPv6 UDP multicast message, how does L3 to L2 address resolution occur?

I think I understand ARP and how this same idea applies to unicast, but I am struggling to grasp the idea of how it works for multicast.

I am aware of MLD and NDP, but not sure how they come into play with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 does not use ARP, it uses ND. ARP uses broadcast, which interrupts every host on the LAN, but IPv6 doesn't have broadcast. Instead, each IPv6 interface must subscribe to a solicited-node multicast address for each IPv6 unicast or anycast address configured on the interface. These solicited-node multicast addresses are based on the IPv6 unicast or anycast addresses, so, in all likelihood, the resolution request only interrupts the one host with that IPv6 address, or possibly a very few hosts. This is a better solution than ARP.

See [*RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Section 2.7.1. Pre-Defined Multicast Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7.1):

> Solicited-Node multicast address are computed as a function of a
> node's unicast and anycast addresses.  A Solicited-Node multicast
> address is formed by taking the low-order 24 bits of an address
> (unicast or anycast) and appending those bits to the prefix
> FF02:0:0:0:0:1:FF00::/104 resulting in a multicast address in the
> range
>
> ```
>      FF02:0:0:0:0:1:FF00:0000
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
>      FF02:0:0:0:0:1:FFFF:FFFF
> ```
>
> For example, the Solicited-Node multicast address corresponding to
> the IPv6 address 4037::01:800:200E:8C6C is FF02::1:FF0E:8C6C.  IPv6
> addresses that differ only in the high-order bits (e.g., due to
> multiple high-order prefixes associated with different aggregations)
> will map to the same Solicited-Node address, thereby reducing the
> number of multicast addresses a node must join.
>
> A node is required to compute and join (on the appropriate
> interface) the associated Solicited-Node multicast addresses for
> all unicast and anycast addresses that have been configured for the
> node's interfaces (manually or automatically).

IPv6 uses the solicited node multicast address for the IPv6 layer-3 unicast or anycast address which it wants to resolve to the layer-2 address. A host will compute the solicited node multicast address for the address to resolve, and it will multicast a Neighbor Solicitation message to the multicast group. The host with the layer-3 address will reply with its layer-2 address.

See [*RFC 4861, Neighbor Discovery for IP version 6 (IPv6)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861):

> Nodes accomplish address resolution by multicasting a Neighbor
> Solicitation that asks the target node to return its link-layer
> address.  Neighbor Solicitation messages are multicast to the
> solicited-node multicast address of the target address.  The target
> returns its link-layer address in a unicast Neighbor Advertisement
> message.  A single request-response pair of packets is sufficient for
> both the initiator and the target to resolve each other's link-layer
> addresses; the initiator includes its link-layer address in the
> Neighbor Solicitation.

To create an IPv6 layer-2 multicast address from an IPv6 layer-3 multicast address you simply use `33-33` and append the last 32-bits of the IPv6 layer-3 multicast address. This gives you a lot more layer-2 multicast addresses than IPv4 has because IPv4 only uses 23 bits of the layer-3 multicast address in the layer-2 multicast address.

See [*RFC 2464, Transmission of IPv6 Packets over Ethernet Networks*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2464):

> 7. Address Mapping -- Multicast
>
> An IPv6 packet with a multicast destination address DST, consisting
> of the sixteen octets DST[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7.1) through DST[16], is transmitted to the
> Ethernet multicast address whose first two octets are the value 3333
> hexadecimal and whose last four octets are the last four octets of
> DST.
>
> ```
>               +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>               |0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1|0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1|
>               +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>               |   DST[13]     |   DST[14]     |
>               +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>               |   DST[15]     |   DST[16]     |
>               +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```

Also, [*RFC 7042, IANA Considerations and IETF Protocol and Documentation Usage for IEEE 802 Parameters, Section 2.3.1. Identifiers Prefixed "33-33"*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7042#section-2.3.1):

> 2.3.1.  Identifiers Prefixed "33-33"
>
> All MAC-48 multicast identifiers prefixed "33-33" (that is, the 2**32
> multicast MAC identifiers in the range from 33-33-00-00-00-00 to
> 33-33-FF-FF-FF-FF) are used as specified in [RFC2464] for IPv6
> multicast.  In all of these identifiers, the Group bit (the bottom bit
> of the first octet) is on, as is required to work properly with
> existing hardware as a multicast identifier.  They also have the Local
> bit on and are used for this purpose in IPv6 networks.
>
> (Historical note: It was the custom during IPv6 design to use "3" for
> unknown or example values, and 3333 Coyote Hill Road, Palo Alto,
> California, is the address of PARC (Palo Alto Research Center,
> formerly "Xerox PARC").  Ethernet was originally specified by the
> Digital Equipment Corporation, Intel Corporation, and Xerox
> Corporation.  The pre-IEEE [802.3] Ethernet protocol has sometimes
> been known as "DIX" Ethernet from the first letters of the names of
> these companies.)

Comment: How does the address mapping of multicast occur? "To create an IPv6 layer-2 multicast address from an IPv6 layer-3 multicast address you simply use 33-33 and append the last 32-bits of the IPv6 layer-3 multicast address." I understand this part, but does the stack take care of this mapping, the kernel, is it part of the neighbor cache? I am trying to understand the internals of how this occurs.

Comment: That is up to the particular OS in use, but OS operations are off-topic here. For instance, in an application opening a multicast socket, how Windows does this can be completely different than how Linux does it.